# Did the Linear Algebra Done Right mistake the hypothesis?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

There are two consecutive exercise in Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right.* Below is the description of the exercises itself and the solutions. I'm not asking for answers, so let us save our time, directly watching the proofs of them.

First, in #14. Why the author require the codomain $W$ to be finite-dimensional? I can't see why. Even in the step we want to extend $S':\text{ran}T\to V$ to $S:W\to V$, what we might need is "$V$" to be finite dimensional right? In case we don't want to use Axiom of Choice. (or even we don't need to use AC, since we just want to prove that we can extend $S'$ to $S$, not extending a subset to a infinite basis. I'm not sure about it.)

Next, in #15. It is also weired that the author require $V$ to be finite dimensional, and let the students using the Rank-Nullity theorem to deduce that $W$ is finite dimensional. And the assumption that $V$ is finite dimensional is no longer use in the proof.

So, did the Linear Algebra Done Right mistake the hypothesis in these two exercise? They should be exchange. (Note that the older version or latest version of the book are all written so.)

[image]
[image]

PS: Below is Exerise 3, if you want to check. [image]

Comment: What is exercise 3?

Comment: @KennyLau Added!

Comment: Exercise 3 starts by saying "Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional". Hence to be applied we need this hypothesis. Indeed, this is to avoid the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: Exercise 3 requires the vector space to be finite dimensional, which is why W is assumed to be finite dimensional.

Comment: @KennyLau Wait, isn't $m=\dim W$? And in #15, the $v_i$ doesn't require to be basis right? Actually, I feel that we don't make special assumptions for $v_i$, they can be even dependent.

Comment: Corrected: for #15, the fact that V is finite dimensional is used to prove that range(T) is finite dimensional, and then using that we construct a finite basis of W.

Comment: So is it better to say "suppose $W$ is finite-dim." instead in the description in the execise?

Comment: @Crostul Do we really need AC to extend $S'$ to $S$? Since we're tempting to extend a map, not extending a subset to a infinite basis. I'm not sure if the former is easier to achieve. (I mean, we construct a proof differs from the figure. I guess that the solution in the figure is non-official.)

Comment: @Eric exercise 3 would need AC to justify that V has a basis, and I refuse to work with infinity without AC.

Comment: @KennyLau Suppose $V$ is infinite-dim vector space, $W$ a vector space. Then there exists a linear transformation $T:V\to W$ such that $T(u_i)=S(u_i)$ for all $i=1,\cdots,m$. Does this claim inevitably using AC? (If we don't follow the proof as in the picture.)

Comment: Why does there exist such a linear transformation?

Comment: @KennyLau Hmm, I see. I'm quite unfamilar with the infinite case.